# Auto-rotate setting disabled permanently on Toshiba AT100

Tags: settings, auto-rotation

About a week ago, the setting for auto-rotate on my Toshiba AT100 (running stock 3.2.1) got permanently disabled somehow, and I am unable to change it. It says it is "on", but the setting is grayed-out, and the screen does not rotate with the device.

Does anyone know how to re-enable this setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/THRiVE-Tablets/Auto-Rotate-disabled-after-updating-to-3-2/td-p/238130) do you have some switch near volume button? If yes, try changing it.

Comment: I'll try this when I get home!

Comment: Bahh, I feel like a wooper now, but it works! Thanks @roxan :)